# How to unmarshal data block from xml

Tags: go

How to unmarshal data from the Item block from XML? Rates and Item blocks have fields with the same names. I get XML data from API and save it to DB, I use gorm for DB.

My code saves data (name and title) from Rates block. I need to save data (name and title) from Item block.

API gives this:

```
<rates>
    <name>text1</name>
    <title>text2</title>
    <item>
        <name>text3</name>
        <title>text4</title>
    </item>
</rates>
```

My Code:

```
type Rates struct {
    XMLName xml.Name     `xml:"rates"`
    Rates   []Item       `xml:"item"`
}

type Item struct {
    Id          int    `xml:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name        string `xml:"name"`
    Title       string `xml:"title"`
}

response, err := http.Get("https://API")
responseData, err := io.ReadAll(response.Body)

var var1 Item 
xml.Unmarshal(responseData, &var1)

if result := h.DB.Create(&var1); result.Error != nil {
    fmt.Println(result.Error)
}

w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/xml")
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
xml.NewEncoder(w).Encode(var1)
```

I removed some unnecessary lines like "if err != nil", so dont pay attention on it.

Comment: what's the content of your response ? if it is a  `<rates>` node you need to unmarshal it to a `Rates` variable.

Comment: @LeGEC Content of response is some service information about http. I tried to unmarshal to Rates variable, but it doesnt work cuz Rates var doesnt contain necessary fields. I need to save data from Item variable, DB has necessary fields for it.

Comment: Please come up with a standalone example showing input (from a literal string), you code and what's the outcome.

Comment: @Volker I edited question to make it more understandable. Input is API link, outcome is wrong data (data from Rates block) written to DB.

Comment: Please provide _literal_ input from your API endpoint. Use that literal in your code. Stop posting code that has nothing to do with your problem (like http).

Comment: (adding to Volker's last comment) "input" meaning: the content of `responseData`. One step is: check that content (it's XML content, correct ?) and write some go structures which accurately match that content (or at least the fragment you need to reach your `Item` part)

Comment: content of responseData is many numbers [60 63 120 109 ... ]. When i unmarshal responseData to var1, var1 contains name and title from Rates block. My structures that i wrote above match to XML data. I don't need any data from Rates struct, so it has only 2 records. I need 2 records from Item struct. As i understand to solve my problem i need to rewrite structs, but how?

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT helped me to solve my problem with adding new structs and additional code:

```
type Rate struct {
    Name   string `xml:"name"`
    Title  string `xml:"title"`
    Items  []Item `xml:"item"`
}

type Item struct {
    Name  string `xml:"name"`
    Title string `xml:"title"`
}

type RateModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name   string
    Title  string
    Item   []ItemModel
}

type ItemModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    RateModelID uint
    Name        string
    Title       string
}

// Create a new RateModel instance
rateModel := RateModel{
    Name:  rate.Name,
    Title: rate.Title,
}

// Convert and save items
for _, item := range rate.Items {
    rateModel.Item = append(rateModel.Item, ItemModel{
        Name:  item.Name,
        Title: item.Title,
    })
}
```